# Slicing an object off of a jQuery collection

Tags: javascript, jquery

These ajax requests are not typical and might take a minute or two each (they are accessing a serial bus).  I first thought `async: false` might work, but found it brought some baggage, so am trying a different approach.  What has got me hung up, however, is how to remove the elements off of the jQuery collection.  How is this accomplished?

PS.  If you have any suggestions on a better approach, please let me know.

```
function processItem(inputs){
    if(!inputs || cancel) return;
    console.log(inputs)
    var input=inputs.shift();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/process',
        data: {id: input.val()},
        timeout: 120000,
        //async: false,
        success: function(response){
            //show as succesfull
            processDiscovery(inputs)
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, status, err) {
            //show as error
            processDiscovery(inputs)
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}

var cancel=false;
$("#cancel").click(function(){
    cancel=true;
});

processItem($('#list input:checked'))
```

Comment: What does "Remove the elements off of the jquery collection" mean? What's the specific input -> output? I'm not understanding

Comment: @NicholasPipitone  Similar to what `.each()` does.  Originally, I was using `.each()` with `async: false`.  I want to get the first element in the collection, get its value for the ajax request, use it to manipulate the DOM, etc.  But then I need to remove it because I am sending the collection to the `processItem` function.  And when all elements have been remove, all is complete.

Comment: As an advice, first, you are using the "old" events of ajax. I truly suggest that instead, you use **.done**, **.fail**, **.always** and .then. jQuery is moving towards a chainable approach for processing events. For better understanding please go to http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/. This will allow you to ajax the calls and don't get lock. Use then wherever method you want to remove or process elements of the collection, (destroy/pop/shift etc..)